# What are the data size limitations when using the GET,PUT methods to get and store objects in an Amazon S3 cloud?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, storage

What is the size of data that can be sent using the GET PUT methods to store and retrieve data from amazon s3 cloud and I would also like to know where I can learn more about the APIs available for storage in Amazon S3 other than the documentation that is already provided.

Answer (score 2):

The `PUT` method is addressed in the respective [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) FAQ [How much data can I store?](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_much_data_can_I_store):

> The total volume of data and number of objects you can store are
>   unlimited. Individual Amazon S3 objects can range in size from 1 byte
>   to 5 terabytes. **The largest object that can be uploaded in a single
>   PUT is 5 gigabytes.** For objects larger than 100 megabytes, customers
>   should consider using the Multipart Upload capability. *[emphasis mine]*

As mentioned, [Uploading Objects Using Multipart Upload API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html) is recommended for objects larger than 100MB already, and required for objects larger than 5GB.

The `GET` method is essentially unlimited. Please note that S3 supports the [BitTorrent protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29) out of the box, which (depending on your use case) might ease working with large files considerably, see [Using BitTorrent with Amazon S3](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/S3Torrent.html?r=3558):

> Amazon S3 supports the BitTorrent protocol so that developers can save
>   costs when distributing content at high scale. [...]

Comment: Correct, There is no limitation over number of object stored on Amazon S3 Bucket. For large file you can upload your data in parts and then merge when all parts get uploaded. I am one of the Developer of Bucket Explorer, Supporting Multipart operation for Amazon S3 Object using Amazon Multipart API for Upload as well as Exclusive Multipart Download Operation.